# $f: A \to B$ is injective if and only if $f(A-X) = f(A) - f(X)$, for all $X\subset A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem. The first part is easy, if $f$ is injective then $f(A-X) = f(A)-f(X)$. But how can I prove that if the equality holds, then $f$ is injective? I built an example in which this does not hold.

Let $f:A \to B$, where $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$. If we choose $X = \{1,3\}$ and put $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 1$, then we have $f(A-X) = f(A) - f(X)$, but this function is not injective. I guess I'm missing something, could you help?

Comment: $f(A-X)=f(A)-f(X)$ for *all* $X\subseteq A$

Comment: It has to hold for all X. Consider X = {1}

Comment: Suppose that $f(A-X)=f(A)-f(X)$ for all $X\subset A$.  In particular when $X=\{x\}$, we have $f(A-\{x\})=f(A)-f(\{x\})$.  Now... $f(x)$ is not an element of the right.  Since it is not an element of the right, it must also not be an element of the left.  Is there then any other $a\in A$ different than $x$ such that $f(a)=f(x)$?  What does that say about injectivity then?

Comment: Worded a different way, suppose $f$ were not injective.  Then there exists elements $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.  Then $f(A-\{x\})$ contains $f(y)$ while $f(A)-f(\{x\})$ does not.